# How can I write a trigger when OWD settings change?

Tags: apex, trigger, owd

Can I write a trigger when OWD settings change in the org?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger works when any DML operation is getting performed on an object (record). When OWD settings is changed Salesforce performs internal sharing and group membership calculations.

We cannot write a trigger on changing of OWD settings.

Comment: Is there any other way than Batch Apex to know about  OWD settings change in the org?

Comment: what's your specific question, provide an example